# Not possible to read legends of pie charts

Tags: python, html, matplotlib

I am using the module matplotlib to create pie charts in picture format. All fine with the charts until the moment I use the .png as images on HTML pages. I need to resize them for 4 or 5x smaller  in the html code (because thy are to big to use them straight away) but then it's not possible to read the legends /values. They become distorted.

I am using

```
plt.savefig('filename.png', dpi = 300)
```

to save the pngs. Already increased the dpi do 1800 but the issue remains.

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of increasing the dpi you probably want to **de**crease it.

```
plt.savefig('filename.png', dpi = 72)
```

If that is not enough, start with a smaller figure already

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
plt.savefig('filename.png', dpi = 72)
```

possibly additionally calling `plt.tight_layout()`

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3), dpi = 72)
# ...
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('filename.png')
```

or saving with `bbox_inches = "tight"

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3), dpi = 72)
# ...

plt.savefig('filename.png', bbox_inches = "tight)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to create a smaller figure at the time of plotting itself.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
```

Comment: I perfectly agree as per the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure) this parameter permits to set the size of the figure in inches. The output will be better if the initial figure is sized before export.